# How to repair this mesh - detach or split options?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

A botched boolean operation has come back to haunt me and Im not sure how to proceed to fix it. The boolean cutter came to close to the outer surface (blue line). I somehow need to detach the mesh(red line) from the outer surface(blue line) and move it back to the left. Any tips? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have repaired this manually by using the following

To see non-manifold geometry:
In edit mode and with vertex mode selected
select -> select all by trait -> non-manifold

To select a non-manifold vertex and to zoom/focus in:
hit "." on the numpad

Delete the non-manifold geometry:
hit the "delete" button for vertex/edge/surface

To manipulate the vertices:
select vertices and press "m" in which various options appear.

The above options helped me rebuild my geometry.